# How to set up web caching settings with GAE using Java?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching

I've been trying to figure out where I can set my cache settings for my website I'm hosting on GAE but I can't find the info on their documentation, nor does Google yield any results. I've read a lot about caching but all the results I find or code examples are using Apache.

Any documentation links? Or just general info of where I actually write the cache settings? Somewhere in `appengine-web.xml` perhaps?

Thanks. Any info/docs at all would be appreciated.

**edit**: I have tried something like this in `appengine-web.xml` but it doesn't seem to be actually caching anything when I test with Chrome Dev Tools —

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/**.png" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.jpg" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.ico" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.js" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.svg" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.ttf" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.woff" expiration="7d" />
    <include path="/**.css" />
</static-files>
```

Also as soon as I add a single static file like this:

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/img/top_img.jpg" expiration="4d 5h" />
</static-files>
```

I get a ton of errors saying that I need to include **everything** in my static-files list, like this — `WARNING: Can not serve /paypal_button.svg directly.  You need to include it in <static-files> in your appengine-web.xml.`

**edit**: here is curl -v log —

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 61009
< Content-Type: text/html
< Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 06:19:21 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
< Server: Development/1.0
< Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 07:33:39 GMT
```

So caching is enabled.. but I cannot figure how how to change expiration dates of individual static files using GAE.

**edit:** when I test on prod server with this code:

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/**.png" expiration="999d" />
</static-files>
```

None of my resources load, I get these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

on everything that isn't a `.png`

Comment: what do you mean by caching there?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I have a website hosted on GAE and I need to set my cache settings for static files (set when they expire, etc)

Comment: like this? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_cache_expiration

Comment: Yeah I tried using that example, but it doesn't seem to be actually caching anything..

Comment: what do you mean? do you see caching headers in http response? or not? on prod env, not dev. provide `curl -v ...` log please

Comment: I'm using GAE dev server, will that not work? I edited comment with curl -v log

Comment: no, it will not work on dev server. check on deployed app

Comment: added an edit, i'm not sure what's going on but as soon as I add a static-file it makes the rest of my files not load. do I need to specify the rest as resource files or something?

Comment: maybe you need to specify all static files, i'm not sure

Comment: I'll mess around with it some more. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after a lot of annoyance I was able to get it to work properly. Basically with `appengine-web.xml` as soon as you list **one** thing as a `<static-file>` you have to list *every* filetype that you have or else it will not know if it's static or not. So I was able to do this—

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/**.png" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.svg" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.jpg" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.zip" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.pdf" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.hex" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.js" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.js.map" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.ttf" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.gif" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.woff" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.css" expiration="365d" />
    <include path="/**.html" expiration="1d"/>
</static-files>
```

and now all the http-headers look correct. Just be sure to include *every* filetype/file you have on your website or else it will not load that resource.

Cheers.